# FFmpeg batch file - combine individual set files with randomized selection from another set of files

Tags: file, batch-file, audio, ffmpeg

I need to combine a specific set of files with a randomized selection from another set of files; for more specific context, voice clips followed by a randomized walky-talky beep. At the moment, I've managed to assemble this so far from searching around:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd beeps
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
cd ..
for %%A IN (*.ogg) DO ffmpeg -y -i radio_beep.wav -i "%%A" -i "beeps\!file[%rand%]!" -filter_complex "[0:a:0][1:a:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outa]" "helper\%%A"
```

At the moment, this will only run the randomization once and use that selection for every file. How can I have it do the randomization for each .ogg in the folder, and get that into FFmpeg as an input?

Comment: Hint: Generate rand inside the loop then `for %%R in (!rand!)`. Suggestion: pre-index the beep file names once by renaming them to have this pattern `beep_#.wav` then `beep_!rand!.wav`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the randomisation for each iteration of the `.ogg` loop.

Here's an example which does that by `Call`ing a labelled section on each iteration:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For %%A In (beeps\*) Do (Set /A i+=1
    Set "file[!i!]=%%A")
For %%A In (*.ogg) Do Call :Process "%%A"
GoTo :EOF

:Process
Set /A "rand=(%RANDOM%%%i)+1"
ffmpeg -y -i "radio_beep.wav" -i %1 -i "!file[%rand%]!" -filter_complex "[0:a:0][1:a:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outa]" "helper\%~nx1"
Exit /B
```